# Events on Calendars in Microsoft Graph is always null?

Tags: azure, api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to access the events of the users that shared their calendars with me. This is the code:

```
 GraphServiceClient graphClient = new(new AzureAuthenticationProvider());

        IUserCalendarsCollectionPage calendar = (
                                                    await graphClient.Me.Calendars
                                                   .Request()
                                                   .GetAsync()
                                               );

public class AzureAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
{
    public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var token = "bearer token";
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    }
}
```

I can access my Calendar and see my events but all the shared calendars that are shared with me have the Events property null:

[image]

I can access the shared calendars events using Postman and the collection is not empty, the issue is when I try to do this using the MS Graph library.

All the examples from Microsoft have bassically the same code as me so I'm not sure what the issue is.